# What is the correct way to use escape_value() in XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl

Can anyone please guide me how to use this escape_value().
I want to escape this characters: `&#xC;` because it gives reference to invalid character number error.

this is my code

```
my $xs = XML::Simple->new( KeepRoot => 1, KeyAttr => 1, ForceArray => 1 );
$xs->XMLout($filename, escape_value(`'&#xC;`')); // but this is not working
my $data = $xs->XMLin($filename);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/grantm/xml-simple/blob/master/lib/XML/Simple.pm), it appears that the `escape_value` method  takes a string and returns returns that string with the following substitutions:

- `>` to `&gt;`
- `<` to `&lt;`
- `&` to `&amp;`
- `"` to `&quot;`

It doesn't even manipulate the structure of the object. If you call it directly, you simply would do this:

```
my $string = '"Remove quotes" & <entities> quotes';
my $encoded_string = $self->escape_value( "$string" );
say $encoded_string;  #&quot;Remove quotes&quot; &amp; and &lt;entities&gt; quotes
```

Heck, why even bother with object orientation?

```
my $string = '"Remove quotes" & <entities> quotes';
my $encoded_string = XML::Simple::escape_value( "$string" );
say $encoded_string;  #&quot;Remove quotes&quot; &amp; and &lt;entities&gt; quote
```

What it looks like is that this subroutine is called by `XMLOut` itself whenever the option `NoEscape` is either not set or set to `0`.

In line 636 of the code, the `XMLOut` method is calling the `value_to_xml` method. This takes the data structure passed into XMLOut and creates an XML text. The `value_to_xml` method then calls the `escape_string` method in line 1431.

Answer (score 1):

U+000C is not allowed in XML.

> `Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]`

Not even escaped.

> Characters referred to using character references MUST match the production for `Char`.

Comment: That's... hmm. interesting. So, base64? :)

Comment: @hobbs, That's an option. You could also use a format better suited for binary data.